# how to put limits on the range in which fsolve is searching for the roots in a nonlinear system of equations: MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to use MATLAB to solve the following nonlinear system of equations.
for example:

```
equation 1:g=g(x,y)

equation 2:h=h(x,y)
```

I am looking for roots (both x and y) in the following range:

```
[0,1]
```

How can I set the lower and upper limit for the searching area when I am using `fsolve`?  I want to stop `fsolve` from searching outside of this range to save time.

Comment: Set the initial point `x0` and then set `diffMaxChange` in [`optimoptions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimoptions.html).

Comment: the diffmaxchange  only sets the maximum possible step sizes for finite differences in gradient estimation. And it can not prevent the solver from searching beyond the range. @ParagS.Chandakkar

Comment: Do you have the symbolic toolbox?

Comment: Yes I do. What is the point by having this toolbox?